# Javascript/NodeJS/Express scope confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I was looking through this repository and noticed that the author had declared a variable (io) in [app.js](https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat/blob/master/app.js#L24):

```
/* Socket.io Communication */
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', socket);
```

He refers to the variable again in [public/js/app.js](https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat/blob/master/public/js/app.js#L6), but doesn't seem to refer to the outer javascript file at all as I would normally expect, so I'm surprised this doesn't result in a ReferenceError.

Could someone please clarify for me what it is about this example that allows this external reference to io to work?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**public/js/app.js** is client-side javascript and will run in the browser. If you look at **index.html**, you'll see the client version of socket.io is included at the bottom which defines a global `io` var.

https://github.com/DanialK/ReactJS-Realtime-Chat/blob/master/public/index.html#L12